# How to change the font in create new project dialog in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am using son of obsidian theme for my visual studio 2019, just notice can't see the text in the tab, I couldn't find anywhere to change this setting in theme colour editor, please see attached image, any idea?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXN8C.png)